# Cakephp makes a unique key validation that I did not ask for

Tags: cakephp

I have a simple table where one of the field is country

It is not defined as unique key in the database and when I try to insert a record with the same country directly in MySql ,  the record is inserted without error. Fine.

But when I tried to insert through a edit screen in my Cakephp application,  I got the error message on the country field  'Alphanumeric'  which does not correspond to the reality because if I enter

for example:  United States which is a country of another existing record,  I got the error,  if I enter xxxxx,  the system accept to save the record.  THat's is why I suspect that there is a check on unique Key.

My model for this field is the following

```
'country' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),

            ),
            'alphanumeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('alphanumeric'),
                            ),
        )
```

Do you have any idea ?   Is there another place where I should check ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"United States" contains a space. The alphanumeric rule won't validate strings with space.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Use this code for unique validation form in cakephp.........**
$validator = $this->validator();
$validator['username'] = array(
    'unique' => array(
        'rule' => 'isUnique',
        'required' => 'create'
    ),
    'alphanumeric' => array(
        'rule' => 'alphanumeric'
    )
);
```